# How to disable the gravity when a character jumps in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am developing a endless runner game in Unity3d and I came across this issue. I have made my character to jump, in doing so, I have used the curve feature in Unity to change the character height and center while jumping.

Then I came across this issue. When I press the jump button I make the animation clip to run in the way that there's no upward thrust or any physics. Simply I'm reducing the collider height and the center points. But in doing so, my character tends to go down due to I have implemented gravity, because eventually my character should fall down.

The only time I don't want to have gravity involved is when I'm jumping (when the jumping animation is running). How do I do this. Or any advice on how to solve this error?

Below is the code I have implemented for jumping.

```
private float verticalVelocity;
public float gravity = 150.0f;
private bool grounded = true;
private bool jump = false;
private float currentY;

private Animator anim;
private AnimatorStateInfo currentBaseState;

private static int fallState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Fall");
private static int rollState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Roll");
private static int locoState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Run");
private static int jumpState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Jump");

private void Update()
{
    currentY = verticalVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    currentBaseState = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    grounded = true;

    if (isGround() && currentY < 0f)
    {
        verticalVelocity = 0f;
        currentY = 0f;
        grounded = true;
        jump = false;
        fall = false;

        if (currentBaseState.fullPathHash == locoState)
        {

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded && currentY == 0f)
            {

                grounded = false;
                jump = true;
                verticalVelocity = 0f; //I have tried here to stop gravity but don't work
                follower.motion.offset = new Vector2(follower.motion.offset.x, verticalVelocity);
            }
        }
        else if (currentBaseState.fullPathHash == jumpState)
        {
            Debug.Log("Jumping state");
            collider.height = anim.GetFloat("ColliderHeight");
            collider.center = new Vector3(0f, anim.GetFloat("ColliderY"), 0f);
        }
    }
    else if (jump)
    {
        follower.motion.offset = new Vector2(follower.motion.offset.x, 0.0f); //I have tried here to stop gravity but don't work
    }
    else
    {
        grounded = false;
        jump = false;
        fall = true;
    }

    anim.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
    anim.SetBool("Jump", jump);
    anim.SetBool("Fall", fall);

    if (fall)
    {
        if (currentBaseState.fullPathHash == fallState)
        {
            Debug.Log("falling");
            collider.height = anim.GetFloat("ColliderHeight");
            collider.center = new Vector3(0f, anim.GetFloat("ColliderY"), 0f);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (currentBaseState.fullPathHash == rollState)
        {
            Debug.Log("Roll");
            collider.height = anim.GetFloat("ColliderHeight");
            collider.center = new Vector3(0f, anim.GetFloat("ColliderY"), 0f);
        }
    }

    MoveLeftRight();
    verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    follower.motion.offset = new Vector2(follower.motion.offset.x, currentY);

    Z - Forward and Backward
    follower.followSpeed = speed; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the gravity of the scene programatically, you can use:

```
if (isGrounded)
{
    Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -9.8f, 0);
} else {
    // Here the value you prefer
    Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -0.1f, 0);
}
```

But with this approach other elements in the scene will not be affected by the gravity neither, and I am not sure if you want this.

So to disable the gravity of a specific GameObject you can write:

```
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.useGravity = false;
```

And another option (I never tried myelf) is this: to apply a force over the GameObject to compensate the force of the gravity (which should be -9.8f in the y axis)

```
private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(transform.down * 9.8f);
}
```

Or maybe with Constant Force:

```
GetComponent<ConstantForce>().force = new Vector3(0, 9.8f, 0);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ConstantForce.html

Comment: Thanks This explains a lot. I'll see what I can do. Thank you @Ignacio Alorre!.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the character options, when you select the object there should be an option to disable physics for it.

Edit: Its under rigidbody.useGravity

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html

Comment: Hi, I don't use rigid-body since it does not go with the code and the plugins I have. I have implemented the gravity on my own here.

Comment: Can you set the gravity variable to 0.0f when you enter the jumping state, and back to 150.0f when you are grounded or falling?

Comment: Where exactly should I do it and how exactly I should implement it? It works though halfway. The jump animation gets stuck at the the end of the clip.

Comment: Why are you setting grounded to true in your `else if(jump)` line? wouldn't it be set to false because you are airborne? Its possible thats the cause of your animation errors.

Comment: Yup slight mistake. Corrected and edited here as well though still don't work. I applied `gravity = 0f` in the `jumpState` checking but the animation gets stuck. I applied back the gravity when  checking `isGround()` still the same issue happens gravity come back. This happens because I make my collider smaller when jumping.